# Are Swift Concurrency tasks run in sequence?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, task

I'm having trouble finding documentation that discusses if Tasks are run concurrently. Or if tasks are run in sequence, in some invisible queue.

The following is a stripped-down problem I'm having with my app, which can be run in a playground, that prompted this question.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Combine

struct Info {
    var id: String
    var value: Int
}

class DataStore {
        // pretend this is storing into core data
    func store(info: Info, id: String) {
        print("    store \(info)")
        let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
        while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < 2 { }  
    }
}

let dataStore = DataStore()
let subj = PassthroughSubject<Info, Never>()
let cancel = subj.sink { info in
    print("Start task for \(info)")
    // is there a way to queue tasks so that we
    Task {
        print("  start \(info)")
        dataStore.store(info: info, id: info.id)
        print("  finish: \(info)")
    }
}

subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 1))
subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 2))
subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 3))
subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 4))

let queueA = DispatchQueue(label: "A", attributes: .concurrent)
let queueB = DispatchQueue(label: "B", attributes: .concurrent)

queueA.async {
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 1))
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 2))
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 3))
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 4))
}

queueB.async {
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 1))
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 2))
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 3))
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 4))
}

queueA.async {
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 1))
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 2))
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 3))
    subj.send(Info(id: "A", value: 4))
}

queueB.async {
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 1))
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 2))
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 3))
    subj.send(Info(id: "B", value: 4))
}

// Note that a closure is not started until the other one has finished
```

Notice how a closure is never started before the previous one has finished. Now I don't know if that's because the passthrough subject is keeping things in sequence or something else with publishers.

I understand it's not a perfect example because of the publisher but my app has old Combine code interfacing with newer async-await code.

P.S. Would it make a difference if I used async sequence instead of a publisher?

Comment: You cannot combine `async/await` with DispatchQueue or Combine (PassthroughSubject etc.) so the whole question is sort of nonsensical.

Comment: Other than the keyword and the Task there is no async await code in the sample above. I suggest watching Meet async/await. The keyword does not make a function concurrent there is quite a bit more to it.

Comment: @loremipsum How would you update the example to be better?

Comment: I don't answer "better" questions, that is highly opinion based and without real code there isn't a complete picture to create an opinion, so it boils down to guessing. The answer you accepted is a decent explanation but also doesn't async and await anything, the `actor` is keeping the calls in order but you can't keep track of what is happening in a true concurrent fashion because the `Task` isn't being "waited" upon. All I can say is watch the videos from WWDC and learn the subject.

Comment: @loremipsum I just want to help you understand as Rob did. He was on the dot. I'm a beginner, is it not reasonable for a beginner to have trouble formulating a perfect example for a concept that she has just come to understand? I updated the example in hopes to help others understand my question.

Comment: You already have an answer that is accepted. That answer explains what you want to know and it answers your hypothetical, There is a tiny blurb on core data, core data comes with `async await` methods for `perform` actions. I don't have anything else to contribute, what do you expect to make "better"?

Comment: @matt I have used Combine with async/await and it works? Why did you say this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr

You are in control of whether the tasks run concurrently or not. But Swift concurrency is not a queue, and you are not assured that they will necessarily run in the order that you created them. Other techniques are needed for strict FIFO behaviors.

---

There are several questions:

1. Does [`Task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5k89c) run concurrently?

   Yes, this is a concurrency system. As soon as you reach an `await` suspension point, other tasks on the same actor are free to interleave, resulting in concurrency.

   Now, your example does not contain `await` suspension points, so there is no opportunity to enjoy concurrency. But, more abstractly, the whole `async`-`await` system is designed with concurrency in mind.
2. Can separate `Task {…}` run in parallel?

   It is not intended for this purpose, but, technically, it depends on whether you launch it from an actor-isolated context or not.

   The whole point of `Task {…}` is to launch a new top-level task *on behalf of the current actor.* So, if you launch it from an actor-isolated context, this new top-level task will be isolated to the same actor, preventing parallel execution (on that actor, at least).

   But if `Task {…}` is launched from a non-actor-isolated context, then the result is that it is not isolated to any particular actor, either. Thus, it may execute in parallel.

   So, bottom line, it depends. But if the intent is parallel execution, I would not be inclined to rely upon this “if called from a non-actor-isolated context, then the `Task` is not actor-isolated either” behavior. I would prefer to be explicit regarding the intent of parallel execution. Specifically, I would would either use `Task.detached {…}`, a task group, or `async let`. You really do not want changes in the caller’s environment to alter your intended parallel execution.
3. Let us assume that you have a series of tasks constructed in such a manner that they do not run concurrently. Does that mean they run sequentially, i.e., FIFO?

   The answer is “no”, the Swift concurrency system does not necessarily run tasks in the order they were submitted. The concurrency system will tend to launch them in the order they were submitted, but not strictly so. (See an example of that below.)

   If you need strict FIFO sequential behavior in the Swift concurrency system, you have to `await` the prior task, or use [`AsyncSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncsequence), such as an [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream/) or [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md).

For more information see WWDC 2021 videos [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/) and [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058)

---

A [`Task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) “[runs] the given ... operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task on behalf of the current actor.” And as the [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID645) says, “actors allow only one task to access their mutable state at a time”. So, in short, if your async-await tasks are on an actor, that will prevent parallel execution.

To illustrate this, I will profile the app in Instruments (with [`OSSignposter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/ossignposter) intervals), so we can easily see a timeline of what’s going on).

Anyway, consider this SwiftUI example where the `Task` is *not* isolated to any particular actor:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import os.log

let poi = OSSignposter(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Launch Ten Tasks") {
                launchTenTasks()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    func launchTenTasks() {
        let experiment = Experiment()

        for i in 0 ..< 10 {
            Task {
                experiment.spin(index: i, for: .seconds(1))
            }
        }
    }
}

class Experiment {
    func spin(index: Int, for duration: Duration) {
        let id = poi.makeSignpostID()
        poi.withIntervalSignpost(#function, id: id, "\(index)") {
            let start = ContinuousClock().now
            while start.duration(to: .now) < duration { }              // blocking thread is bad idea, but just simulating some slow, synchronous task
        }
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

You can see that the tasks are running in parallel.

Now this is bit of an exception to the rule. This is merely a demonstration that using `Task` would not necessarily be sufficient, alone, to avoid parallel execution.

But we often use tasks in conjunction with an actor. In that case, you *do* achieve non-parallel execution.

So, if I make the `Experiment` an actor, the methods will be actor-isolated, and therefore will not run in parallel. Or if `Task {…}` was actor isolated, then again, these synchronous function calls will not run in parallel, either.

To illustrate this, one could make it run on the main actor with `@MainActor` qualifier (which would be bad in this example, because it would block the main thread). Or you could isolate it to your own actor:

```swift
actor Experiment {
    func spin(index: Int, for interval: TimeInterval) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

I would draw your attention to the fact that this achieves serial behavior, but this is *not* a queue. Note that items 8 and 9 are not in order. (They process largely in order, but not strictly so.) If you wanted queue-like behavior where items are processed in a strictly FIFO manner, you would use an [`AsyncSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncsequence), such as an [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream/) or an [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md).

---

In your case, if your `DataStore` was an actor, that would prevent concurrent execution. And, FWIW, `store` should not be marked as an `async` method, because it does nothing asynchronous (at least, at this point).

A few other caveats about your example:

1. Your task is so quick that it is hard to see if it is really running sequentially or in parallel: Note that I performed my tests with an artificially slower example, precisely to clearly manifest parallel vs non-concurrent execution.
2. You did your tests in a playground: IMHO, playgrounds are not a good environment for testing concurrency. You want to run this in a test app that runs in an environment that parallels that of your final target platform. Playgrounds feature all sorts of idiosyncratic behaviors from which it would be too easy to draw incorrect conclusions.
3. I would advise against mixing Combine and (especially) GCD with async-await code.
4. I would avoid using [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) (e.g., `Task {…}` and `Task.detached {…}`) whenever possible. Sure, we have to use these patterns when bridging from a synchronous context to an asynchronous one, but otherwise we would use it sparingly. With unstructured concurrency, we bear the responsibility of manually propagating cancelation to tasks we create. And if you do not save the resulting `Task` object in some property, you lose the ability to cancel it later.

So, run it in a real app, and if you want to ensure it will not run in parallel, make sure your method is isolated to an actor.

Comment: I know it's against the rules but thank you. I had trouble formulating a good example and I believe that I was using the wrong terminology.  I changed the question itself to be on Swift Concurrency Tasks and I used your code to waste time. Would that have made the question better?

Comment: I'll be sure to remember to not use playgrounds for Swift Concurrency, due to its strange behavior.

Comment: @Petar – I’d suggest we move this to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256230/are-swift-concurrency-tasks-run-in-sequence). I might suggest that you delete your comments above, now that we're connected in chat.